# Inverse Laplace Transform and Partial Fractions Decomposition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Inverse Laplace Transformation

$F(s)=4\frac{s^2-3s+11}{(s^2-4s+8)(s+3)}$

I need help with this question. I should use partial fractions but and separate the denominators but what would happened with the numerator being multiplied by 4.

Comment: The Laplace operator is linear which means the transform of a constant times a function is equal to the constant times the transform, same goes in reverse

Comment: so basically the numerator will go away and we will be left of with 4/(s^2-4s+8) and 4/(s+3) correct

Comment: @NonorValenz Hopefully this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since \begin{align}F(s)=4(\frac{1}{s+3}+\frac{1}{s^2-4s+8})\end{align}
The then bring about a more useful form one can do the following:
\begin{align*}4(\frac1{s+3}+\frac12\frac{2}{(s-2)^2+4})\end{align*}
Now we can take the Laplace inverse and get the following: \begin{align}4e^{-3t}+2e^{2t}\sin(2t)\end{align}